# Admin app with React - how not to expose APIs until login succeeds?

Tags: authentication, reactjs, react-router, jwt, react-redux

Here is the workflow I want to implement for admin module of a site

1. Show a login screen - will be a React component
2. If login fails, the above component will show an error message
3. If login succeeds, the view changes. The new view should contain links to APIs **/addProduct** and **/deleteProduct**
4. One way is to create one single App but I don't want to expose API urls to the client unless the login succeeds.
5. How do I achieve UI seperation here?

Comment: are you using webpack? If so I have good solution.

Comment: Yes I am. Please let me know. @free-soul

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you have two options:

1. Use the login response to return the list of links.
2. Have a set endpoint that only works with an authenticated client that returns the list of links.